# Choosing the right voltage regulation - 12/24V to 5V

Tags: voltage-regulator

for my projects I always come across the power part which kinda bugs me. Usually i just open the TI webbench, put my parameters into and take whatever he gives me. But is that the right/good way?

Why and where do I choose linear vs step regulation? low heat low noise?

Example : Input Voltage 12/24VDC, Output Voltage  = 5VDC/3A max - pref. low noise > low temp

TI now gives me multiple choices:
TPS56339 - buck, seems good to me or the
LM604x0 - synchron step down -
LMR33630 - synchron step down  dont really seem to see a difference between these 2

Because all of theese are via switching I have to reduce the output noise, I didnt choose yet so I cant say how. Is there any way to choose the "best" one ?

Another questions about voltage regulation - is there a way to always get the desired output voltage even with 2 different input ? Same parameters as before, but I "dont know" which one is it, so I cant make a switch/jumper, but I always need a stable 5V output. ideas?

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: At 3A you can not feasibly do the voltage drop from 24 V to 5 V with a linear regulator - that'd be nearly 60 W of waste heat. So, you're right to choose switching regulators. What you now need to define is what "low noise" actually means. It's often easiest to first define what frequency ranges your circuitry is sensitive at, and work from there. Even better would be if you could specify a maximum allowed noise power spectral density, but that might be hard. After that, it becomes clearer what you need.

Comment: But that is what regulators do, take in voltage and output stable voltage. The regulator and the components around it just has to be chosen so that it works properly on both voltages or a range of voltages. And since we don't know what you are powering with 5V we can't know if you need low noise or not or what is best. Usually, best is always a compromise between dozens of things, such as price, PCB area, efficiency etc.

Comment: The Load are MOSFETs or POWERMOSFETs and an ESP32
Is there a good simulation software for low voltage regulation ? I have PLECS but this seems to only be good for high voltage

Comment: None of these require "low noise", besides ESP32 has an onboard voltage regulator as the chip uses 3V3 so it can tolerate lots of ripple on 5V.

Comment: So if the FETs are the load, are you using them as heaters? Or using them to control actual loads like lamps, motors etc?

Comment: 5 volts is not adequate to drive the gate of most power MOSFETs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why and where do I choose linear vs step regulation? low heat low noise?

A linear regulator is typically used when a low noise output is desired and/or when the PSU is required to not emit a lot of EMI. A linear regulator is a very simple type of regulator which works by dropping excess input voltage to maintain a constant output voltage. Linear regulators are easy to use and only need a few complimentary components. However, they can be extremely inefficient, especially when there is a large voltage difference between the input and the output.

Let us take your example specs - Input Voltage: 12/24VDC, Output Voltage: 5VDC/3A max

The power dissipated in a linear regulator is (Vin - Vout) * Iout.

If the input voltage is 24V, then the power dissipated is (24 - 5) * 3 = 57W. This requires some serious amount of heatsinking and is generally not a feasible idea.

A buck converter is a switch-mode DC-DC converter which is a much more efficient solution to step down 24V to 5V at 3A. Assuming an efficiency of 90%, the power dissipated in the buck converter circuit will be around 1.5W, which is reasonable. However, buck converters usually have more complimentary components than a linear regulator, and the complimentary components must be carefully chosen (like you must only use low ESR capacitors) and they do feature a noisy output.

But if you want low noise **and** low power dissipation, you must use **both** types of regulators in a cascade configuration. It looks like you are a beginner, so this might not be the best solution for you as it is a complex one. So I suggest using a simple buck converter to efficiently step down 24/12V to 5V and not worry too much about the output noise.

> Another questions about voltage regulation - is there a way to always get the desired output voltage even with 2 different input ? Same parameters as before, but I "dont know" which one is it, so I cant make a switch/jumper, but I always need a stable 5V output. ideas?

The simplest solution is to use two diodes as shown:

[image]

Use Schottky diodes that have an appropriate current rating. There are other methods, but this is the simplest one.